# Airflow RBAC UI cannot toggle DAGS with error "the CSRF token is missing"

Tags: airflow, flask-appbuilder

On Airflow version 1.10.9 I am not able to switch on/off the DAGS using the RBAC UI. Airflow shows:

`INFO - The CSRF token is missing`

In chrome tools I can see the CSRF token is not sent with the http request.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an upgrade of jQuery in the Flask-AppBuilder dependency. It affects Airflow `1.10.9` and `1.10.10` with Flask-AppBuilder on version `2.3.3`.

**Fix: Downgrade Flask-AppBuilder to** `2.3.2`.

Reference to Flask-AppBuilder issue:

https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1362

Reference to Airflow issues:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8613

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8599

Answer (score 0):

You can actually upgrade to Flask-AppBuilder 2.3.4 released today ;)